# Cannot move out of shared reference: the case for converting to an external error type

Tags: rust

Consider the following code:

```
struct foo{
    bar:i32
}
struct InternalError {}
struct PubError {}

fn process_inner(s:&str) -> Result<foo, InternalError> {
    Ok(foo{bar:45})
}
fn process_outer(s:&str)-> Result<foo,PubError> {
    let r = process_inner(&s);
    let r2 = &r.ok().unwrap();
    return Ok(*r2);
}
```

This does not compile and produces the `error[E0507]: cannot move out of '*r2' which is behind a shared reference` error.

The real case as you can imagine is a little more complex, but this illustrates just as well the goal to convert an inner module error to something easier to handle by calling code outside a module.

We could otherwise use `return Ok(r)` (using the same error type), but that does not convert the error type.

I also know I can implement copy, but I still want to know if it's possible by moving.

Comment: Are you aware of the `?` operator?

Comment: Also this code is bizarre; you only get the error because you're artificially making `r2` a reference. Just `let r2 = r.ok().unwrap();` and `return Ok(r2);` would [compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=40055ac84ba843a816eb0d71e0ebcfff). But that isn't the real solution since that wouldn't propagate any internal errors (it would panic on `.unwrap()` if `process_inner` failed).

Comment: *We could otherwise use return Ok(r) (using the same error type), but that does not convert the error type.* - `return Ok(r)` wouldn't compile because it would wrap `Result` in another `Result`, you'd use `return r`. But if that's ok with you, then you obviously don't  have just a reference to `r`, so you might as well do `r.map_err(|int_err| PubError {})`, which does the conversion you're after. You can also implement `From<InternalError> for PublicError` in which case you can let the `?` operator deal with error conversion (and `map_err(Into::into)` will work too).

Comment: @kmdreko I omitted the error handling code (but in the real case it's needed, and avoids panic). But your suggestion is the correct one (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think this encapsulates why `rustc` will not compile your code, I've stripped out code from your example which I think is unnecessary.

```
struct Foo{
    bar: i32,
}

fn bar() -> Foo {

    // Create an instance of Foo, and set r1 as a reference to Foo in memory.
    let val = Foo { bar: 45 };
    let r1 = &val;

    // Attempt to dereference r1, since Foo does not implement the Copy trait, the dereference operator is going to attempt to move the memory that r1 points to, and use that as our return value.
    // ... which is not allowed in Rust, as the shared reference `val` has ownership of that memory, this code violates ownership and borrowing rules.
    return *r1;
}
```

Comment: Hi! You could improve your answer with a good example (the code that would compile), and also pay attention that `fn bar()` should have a return type like this `fn bar() -> Foo` otherwise it doesn't compile because of a wrong function prototype, not because of the shared reference problem.

Comment: I omitted the error handling code in `process_outer`, but I actually need it in the real case, hence the different `Result<...>`

Answer (score 0):

(Thanks @kmdreko)

```
struct foo{
    bar:i32
}
struct InternalError {}
struct PubError {}

fn process_inner(s:&str) -> Result<foo, InternalError> {
    Ok(foo{bar:45})
}
fn process_outer(s:&str)-> Result<foo,PubError> {
    let r = process_inner(&s);
    // Handle the error and convert / return the PubError if needed
    // If no error:
    let r2 = r.ok().unwrap(); // instead of &r.ok()...
    return Ok(r2); // instead of Ok(*r2)
}
```

This moves the value already inside `process_outer` instead of taking a reference to the intermediate result, which can then be (move-)returned.